# Docking a fragment window in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is it possible to have two fragments - one on the left which controls the one on the right, and dock and undock the left fragment such that on docking the one on the left, only the fragment on the right occupies the screen ? If so how?

Comment: this question is extremely hard to understand. try to rephrase it a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can create a horizontal linear layout as your main layout for your activity and within that layout add two linear layouts that will be the place holders for your two fragments ie leftLinLayout and rightLinLayout. When the activity loads add the two fragments dynamically to the two layouts using a FragmentTransaction.

Within the fragments it is possible to get a reference to other fragments since you have method getActivity() then you call the fragment manager and find the fragment  you want to manipulate or remove. However this is not desirable. The better solution would be to build a callback interface that the host activity has to implement so that it becomes a listener to your fragment events and then you let the activity add/remove the desired fragments.  A good example of this implementation is the newsreader app in the android developer reference http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html .